# How to say that you feel apologetic toward someone?

Tags: phrase-request

I'm trying to construct a sentence in which the speaker 'feels apologetic' toward someone. I want to avoid hinting at a sense of guilt or shame etc so that rules out 'I felt contrite/ rueful/ regretful/ remorseful/ repentant/ guilty' and similar sentences.

The context where I want to use this is:

> However, no matter how much heart he had put into it I could not
> possibly hand out those paper bundles to the readers. I showed him the
> booklet I had brought with me. I had put in hours of painstaking
> effort in arranging the entire content myself. His eyes grew wide as
> he turned over the pages one by one, and I felt apologetic toward him.

Here's what I thought of:

> I felt bad for him.
>
> I felt sorry for him.

But these sentences imply 'pity/empathy' which is not what I aiming for.

The sentence I came up with finally is:

> I felt apologetic toward him.

But I've never heard anyone speak this way. Is this idiomatically correct? Or is there a better way of saying this?

Comment: If you could provide a context or a story, it would make it easier to find an appropriate phrase.

Comment: @Xantix I have updated my post with the content.

Comment: @ Soulz: I've just posted my answer, but now I read the question more carefully, I'm confused. If you don't feel *sorry* for the person, and you don't feel *guilty* either, I don't understand what [emotional?] reaction you're trying to convey.

Answer (score 5):

So, the situation is that both person A and person B have brought things to hand out, and both have spent hours on those things, not knowing the other was also doing it; and person B's handouts are clearly superior to person A's?

Then at this point where Person B sees person A realizing that A's efforts are completely overshadowed, B is feeling that it is unfortunate that A wasted all that time doing something that turns out fruitless.  Either there is empathy involved (B feels bad because he knows that A feels bad) or there is not (B merely regrets the lost opportunity to have A be doing something useful, or B is happy to outshine A).

If there is some level of empathy involved (and since person B feels "apologetic", it seems that there must be some), then either "felt bad for" or "felt sorry for" would be appropriate and idiomatic.

Comment: Following a more careful reading of the question I now think this is the only answer that makes sense. More properly, I should say I don't think the question *as framed* makes sense anyway - OP says he doesn't feel either pity or guilt, but I can barely imagine any other reactions - certainly nothing so simple it could be succinctly expressed in English.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this idiomatically correct?

*Apologetic* means "feeling or showing that you are sorry for doing something wrong or for causing a problem."

> "Sorry," she said, with an apologetic smile.

> They were very apologetic about the trouble they'd caused.

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) has 846 sentences containing *apologetic*, but only six sentences containing *feel apologetic*. One of those sentences is taken from *Man on a turquoise-colored cloud* by Barbara Haas.

> I feel apologetic for our warmth-our fire roaring in the grate, our sweaters, our cooking smells.

The [Corpus of Web-Based Global English](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/) has 2504 sentences containing *apologetic*, and 26 sentences containing *feel apologetic*. 561 sentences containing *apologetic* are written in American English, and 575 in British English; for sentences containing *feel apologetic*, those numbers become 5 and 4 respectively.

Comment: So what is your opinion of the OP's suggested sentence? You've talked a lot about how "apologetic" is used, but haven't stated whether the you believe suggested usage is good, and if not, what an alternative might be.

Answer (score 1):

OP seems to understand the difference between feeling *sorry* for someone (empathising with their plight, which you didn't necessarily cause), and feeling *apologetic* towards them (where *you feel responsible* for their unhappy circumstance, and are perhaps minded to explicitly apologise for your involvement).

The reason people might think it's "not idiomatic" to say you [*felt apologetic **toward***](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22felt%20apologetic%20toward%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (or BrE [***towards***](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22felt%20apologetic%20toward%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20apologetic%20towards%22&oq=%22felt%20apologetic%20towards%22&gs_l=serp.3...5258.5258.1.5968.1.1.0.0.0.0.47.47.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.15.serp.D49J3C4GBrg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916)) someone is mainly because the sentiment itself isn't something we normally say (we're much more likely to either simply say we *feel **sorry for** him*, or ***guilty about*** [whatever we did to him].

Because we don't often say it, people aren't sure which preposition to use. Here are a few examples of [*felt apologetic **to** him*](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22felt%20apologetic%20toward%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20apologetic%20to%20him%22&oq=%22felt%20apologetic%20to%20him%22&gs_l=serp.3...10402.11152.10.11519.4.4.0.0.0.0.51.197.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.15.serp.gj25qcnkWAU&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916)/[her](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22felt%20apologetic%20toward%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20apologetic%20to%20her%22&oq=%22felt%20apologetic%20to%20her%22&gs_l=serp.3...62888.66734.13.67285.15.12.3.0.0.0.114.764.10j2.12.0...0.0...1c.1.15.serp.MDmp35PPdDc&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916), for example (there's no "rule of grammar" saying that's actually wrong).

And although again it's uncommon, there's also [*felt apologetic **for** him*](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22felt%20apologetic%20toward%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20apologetic%20for%20him%22&oq=%22felt%20apologetic%20for%20him%22&gs_l=serp.3...7601.8256.15.8502.4.3.1.0.0.0.71.195.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.15.serp.DNswT9KrtPE&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916)/[her](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22felt%20apologetic%20toward%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20apologetic%20for%20her%22&oq=%22felt%20apologetic%20for%20her%22&gs_l=serp.3...46824.47436.16.48229.4.4.0.0.0.1.111.271.3j1.4.0...0.0...1c.1.15.serp.TCdbwdNfyNo&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916). But that has a somewhat different sense (it means you felt you should apologise *to other people* for what he/she is/did/does).

---

In almost all relevant contexts, it's probably obvious *who* we're feeling apologetic towards, so it's my opinion that people often don't bother trying to specify the person - partly because it's redundant, and partly because (like OP) they're unsure how to express it correctly (i.e. - with the "right" preposition).

Comment: I like your "guilty about" alternative. The O.P. might even say something like: _Feelings of guilt washed over me._ As a footnote, I know the O.P. said, "I want to avoid hinting at a sense of guilt or shame," but I think there's an almost idiomatic difference between _admitting guilt_ (which somehow conveys fault), and _feeling guilty_ (which is almost more like a sense of pity).

Comment: @J.R.: Even in the real world (or should I say the *unreal* world, of people's poorly-understood emotions), it's not uncommon for someone to feel guilty about another's suffering despite having done nothing to cause it. Or even to feel guilty about *their own* suffering when they're "objectively blameless". Particularly, that applies to victims of sexual crimes, where the emotional baggage often completely crowds out rational thought.

Answer (score 0):

#### Apologetic

*This section was rewritten based on comments and other answers.

> John was apologetic.

In the previous sentence, I would understand that John said "I'm sorry" more than once, or at least wanted to.

> John was an apologetic.

This uses a different meaning of "apologetic", which you don't want ("To Argue For or Defend a Position").

> John was apologetic toward Mary.

This doesn't sound very idiomatic. It is understandable, but "John was apologetic to Mary" would be much more common.

> John felt apologetic toward Mary.

This version sounds less idiomatic than the version using "was".

#### Empathy

Both "I felt bad for him" and "I felt sorry for him" are very idiomatic and sound natural, but they do carry an amount of empathy.

But, empathy is a scale, so perhaps they are near enough.

Here are a few examples ordered according to decreasing empathy.

> When I saw him, I just couldn't go on.
>
> When I saw him, part of me died inside.
>
> When I saw him, I couldn't stand it.
>
> I felt terrible for him.
>
> I feel for him.
>
> I felt bad for him.
>
> I felt sorry for him.
>
> I felt uncomfortable when I heard his story.
>
> It bothered me a little to see him like that.
>
> His conditions bothered me somewhat.
>
> I felt like he deserved an apology.
>
> I thought "c'est la vie", and walked on by.
>
> I didn't feel any sympathy for him.
>
> May he starve to death, that annoying nuisance.

edited given context:

I would recommend one of the following:

> I felt he was due an apology.
>
> I felt sorry for him.
>
> I felt he deserved an apology.

Comment: Apologetic, while it is used to discuss the logical defense of a belief or stance (e.g. Christian Apologetics), the word "apologetic" can absolutely still be used to mean "feeling or showing that you are sorry for doing something wrong or for causing a problem", as @kiamlaluno suggested. See his answer for more details on the use of this word.

Comment: that's right. edited.

Comment: "Apologetic toward" can still be used to mean roughly "feeling or demonstrating sadness for a problem caused". e.g., "The waitress spilled my drink on me; as I dried my shirt, she was very apologetic toward me, showering me with statements of 'I am *so* sorry' and 'I am just so clumsy!'"

Comment: The only case where "apologetic" has the meaning you stated above is when used within a very specific contexts, generally as a noun. e.g. Mormon Apologetics, Jewish Apologist, etc. If used as an adjective or adverb, I'd have a hard time coming up with an example using the above meaning, other than perhaps to describe a logical argument, e.g. "His apologetic treatise on Creationism", though I don't actually know whether this is proper.

Comment: rewrote that section entirely, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Even after the changes, I think there are still a lot of highly-questionable aspects to this answer. For example, using *apologetic* as a noun is rare/nonstandard - it's *apologist*. From my own answer, *felt apologetic toward* and *towards* both have hundreds of written citations, whereas *felt apologetic **to*** has only 7. And there's no meaningful idiomatic preference between *to be* and *to feel* in respect of emotional states such as *apologetic, excited, miserable*, etc.